# System not booting up after OS X Update 10.8.5

Tags: macos, mac, boot, updates, nomachine

I am new to MAC (and also to this forum).

Yesterday, I updated my OS to 10.8.5 and I am unable to boot it again. On boot up, it shows some error message on black screen with some message:

A part of which is:
"Kernel extensions in backtrace:
com.apple.iokit.IOPCFamily...
com.nomachine.driver.nxusb.io...

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: nxusbd"

Then it shows message saying

"Your system was restarted because of some error. Press a key or wait a few seconds to continue starting up". After this message, it again goes to login interface again.

I tried to restart multiple times but it doesn't help.

I can start in safe mode but functionalities are very limited and I am not able to work. Also tried to install combo update for 10.8.5 but it din't help either.

I found that we cannot roll back to a previous version. My time machine was not enabled till now. I connected a HDD but it is not detected so unable to do anything. I am not sure how much it will help anyway.

As per the stacktrace, could it be the case that NoMachine is not compatible with recent version?

Please provide the steps I should take. Please provide low level details, if possible, as I am quite new to MAC.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you able to use your USB stick / DVD to reinstall OS X? You may also try, before doing that, run disk utility (with the USB stick / DVD that came with your computer, even the repair partition) then fix permissions, since that may be the issue. When booting, hold the Option key and select your other, "recovery" partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem folks.

NoMachine version was not compatible with the MAC OSX 10.8.5.

Restarted in safe mode, removed no machine and it worked :)